# How To Delete All Words After X Characters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I read this post: [sed delete remaining characters in line except first 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718326/sed-delete-remaining-characters-in-line-except-first-5) which helps me to delete all characters after x. However, I'm having a hard time finding how to delete all words after x characters.

I started with this code:

```
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | sed 's/.//30g'
#character 30 ---------------------^
```

My attempt:

```
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | sed 's/ .* //30g'
#character 30 ---------------------^
```

In these outputs, I either cut off the last word or counting words. Instead, I need to remove the words after 30 characters. I am running this on various lines/word lengths so that's why I can't just set it to the end of the word.

Desired output:

```
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant
```

If you know how to put together counting the words after x characters, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Please note: As stated earlier, **do not change the code to 33 or 34 characters**. The point of the question is to remove all WORDS after 30 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **awk** will do

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="" }  length>30{i=30; while($i~/\w/) i++; NF=i-1; }1' file
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant
This line has 22 chars
```

Setting `FS=OFS=""` so that each char is considered as a field

If `length>30` then `i=30; while($i~/\w/) i++;` i.e keep incrementing `i` until we land at a non-alnum character;  Once loop ends set the desired `NF`.

The line with `length<=30` will be printed as it is.

Using **grep**

```
$ grep -oE "^.{1,29}\w*" file
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant
This line has 22 chars
```

`^.{1,29}\w*` : `1` to `29` because if `30th` char is non-alnum then it shouldn't be considered.

Comment: Grep solution is the shortest one, I was trying to solve this with grep too but forgot about `^` and it produced multiple lines.

Comment: @PawełTatarczuk @batMan, I actually used Pawel's solution in my program. But, I chose this because of the dual answer of `awk` and `grep`. Also, it has the highest score and I did owe you one batMan. Pawel, I hope a lot of people upvote your answer because you gave a very very helpful explanation. It helped me greatly and will help others too. Thanks once again batMan :-)

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: The issue in Pawel's solution is : If 30th char is space it will still print the next word starting from 31st.

Comment: You should mention the awk solution is gawk-specific due to 1) relying on FS="" splitting the record into characters, 2) use of `\w` for word-constituent characters (you should be using `\S` instead btw), and 3) relying on decrementing NF to remove fields from the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

How about simple and sober awk with it's magical substr utility:

```
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | awk '{print substr($0,1,34)}'
```

In case you want to pass length to awk then following may help you in same.

```
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | awk -v end=34 '{print substr($0,1,end)}'
```

In case you want to have your length save in a shell variable and want to pass it to awk then following may help you in same.

```
val="34"
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | awk -v var="$val" '{print substr($0,1,var)}'
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a sed solution on same too.

```
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | sed 's/\(.\{34\}\)\(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: @DomainsFeatured, your welcome. See my EDIT added 3 more ways(including sed) to solve this problem, let me know if any queries on same.

Comment: Oh crap, I just realized this doesn't work! I need it to work on 30 characters, not 34 :-( The output is: `StackOverflow Users Are Brilli`

Comment: @DomainsFeatured, I had given that 34 characters solution because I have seen your expected output(which was there till Brilliant word), obviously you could adjust characters as per your need.

Comment: @Down voter: Please let me know the reason for down vote?

Comment: In the question I put: In these outputs, I either cut off the last word or counting words. Instead, I need to remove the words after 30 characters. I am running this on various lines/word lengths so that's why I can't just set it to the end of the word.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with sed:

```
echo "StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working" | sed 's/\(.\{1,30\}\w*\)\(.*\)/\1/'
```

This should work for text shorter than 30 characters as well - no trimming happens in that case.

**Explanation**

This is the regex I started with:

```
.{1,30}\w*
```

It simply gets 1-30 characters and then all additional word characters that are right after.

Now to be able to use it in sed we had to strip out everything else we need two groups:

```
(.{1,30}\w*)(.*)
```

Now some escaping for '()' and '{}':

```
\(.\{1,30\}\w*\)\(.*\)
```

This can go to sed:

```
sed 's/<pattern>/<replacement>/<flags>'
```

We want to remove second group, so as the replacement in sed we use '\1' (first group):

```
echo "..." | sed 's/\(.\{1,30\}\w*\)\(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: Hey Pawel, yes! This is what I was looking for. If you could provide an explanation for the `\(.\{1,30\}\w\+\)\(.*\)/\1` part, I would love to learn. Otherwise, thanks for the help. I'll mark the best answer later today :-)

Comment: There was minor mistake, I edited the answer. I'll write an explanation in minutes.

Comment: Explanation added

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very clear and easy to understand. I appreciate the knowledge :-) I'm sure this will help other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{30}\S*).*/\1/' file
```

This retains the first 30 characters and any following non-space characters.

N.B. if the 30th character is a space, the following word will be included, so the regexp might be:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{29}\S*).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: Hey @potong, thanks for the awesome answer and explanation. That makes a lot of sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

With bash

```
var="StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working"
echo ${var:0:30}
```

Or

```
expr substr "$var" 1 30
```

Comment: Not working for me...I get output: `StackOverflow Users Are Brilli`

Comment: sorry, i understand you want to stop after 30 char

Comment: yes, but I need to include the rest of the word `StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant`. Your output cuts `Brilliant` into `Brilli`

Comment: Ok, with bash : var="StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working"
var1=${var#*${var:0:30}}
echo ${var%${var1#* }}

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(.{30}\S*).*/,"\\1",1)} 1' file
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant
```

or GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{30}\S*).*/\1/' file
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant
```