# How To Delete All Words Before X Characters

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm using code from this question [How To Delete All Words After X Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746639/how-to-delete-all-words-after-x-characters) and I'm having a trouble keeping (not deleting) all the words after 30 characters.

Original code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="" }  length>30{i=30; while($i~/\w/) i++; NF=i-1; }1'
```

My attempt:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="" }  length>30{i=30; while($i~/\w/) i++; NF=i+1; }1'
```

Basically, I understand I need to change the `NF` which was `NF=i-1` so I tried changing it to `NF=i+1` but obviously I'm only getting one field. How can I specify `NF` to print the rest of the line?

Sample data:

```
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant And Hard Working
#character 30 ---------------^
```

Desired output:

```
And Hard Working
```

If you could please help me keep the rest of the line by using `NF`, I would really appreciate your positive input and support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier using `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP '^.{30}\w*\W*\K.*' file

And Hard Working
```

Where `\K` is used for reseting matched information.

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `.{30}`: Match first 30 characters
- `\w*`: followed by 0 or more word characters
- `\W*`: followed by 0 or more non-word characters
- `\K`: reset matched information so far
- `.*`: Match anything after this position

---

Using `awk` you can use this solution:

```
awk '{sub(/^.{30}[_[:alnum:]]*[[:blank:]]*/, "")} 1' file

And Hard Working
```

---

Finally a `sed` solution:

```
sed -E 's/^.{30}[_[:alnum:]]*[[:blank:]]*//' file

And Hard Working
```

Comment: Hey Anubhava, thanks for the answer. This does indeed work. I'm upvoting because both are great and you provided the code that gets the output I wanted. I'm going to leave the question open in case someone does answer the question about using NF. Thanks so much Anubhava.

Comment: Unless...I change the title of the question to "How To Delete All Words Before X Characters" but I think that would defeat the purpose of me trying to figure out how to use `NF` to print remaining fields. It's up to you guys.

Comment: A longer awk solution using your approach may be: `awk -v len=30 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} length > len{for(i=1; i<=len; i++) $i=""; for(; $i ~ /\w/; i++) $i=""; for(; $i ~ /\W/; i++) $i=""} 1' file`

Comment: Wow, that's a good one. Works again :-) I guess there's no way to do it with `NF`. Will mark you as the correct answer in the next day or so unless we get another way. Hopefully, other people will like your answer too.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured why are you interested in involving NF in this? NF is the number of fields on a line but you're not doing anything with fields at all and even if you were it's not clear how NF would be a factor. Asking how to split a line at a space using NF is like asking how dig a hole using a napkin - leaves the rest of us going "huh?".

Comment: @EdMorton Hey Ed,  in order to ask a good question and to show that I was working through something, I tried to explain where I was starting and where I was stuck. Even though, I could've done it with grep,  I was interested to learn more about NF and  if using that to capture the rest of the line would have been possible. It seems like it's not possible so I have updated the question to reflect what everyone has answered. Hopefully  that makes sense I was just trying to  explain and ask equality a question of where I was stuck.

Comment: It's not a question of possible or not, anything's possible in software so you can come up with a solution that has `NF` in it somewhere, but it'd just be pointless as there's far simpler, more obvious and generally better solutions. `NF` is just a variable that holds the number of fields - nothing obviously related to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
awk '{print substr($0, index(substr($0,30),FS)+30)}'
```

find the delimiter index after the 30th char, take a substring from that index on.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why your considering anything related to NF for this since you're not doing anything with fields, you're just splitting each line at a blank char. It sounds like this is all you need for both questions, using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(.{30}\S*)\s+(.*)/,"\\1",1)}' file
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant

$ awk '{print gensub(/(.{30}\S*)\s+(.*)/,"\\2",1)}' file
And Hard Working
```

or it's briefer using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{30}\S*)\s+(.*)/\1/' file
StackOverflow Users Are Brilliant

$ sed -E 's/(.{30}\S*)\s+(.*)/\2/' file
And Hard Working
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of NF, you can try

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a+=length($i)+1;if(a>30){for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++)b=b $j" ";print b;exit}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -c30- file | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

this will keep only the words that start after 30th character (index >= 31)